# Javascript "object" not retaining css values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm defining a javascript "object" via the following function:

```
function Window(vars) {
    this.div = $("<div/>", {
        id: vars.id,
        class: vars.styles + " box text",
        css: {
            top: vars.top,
            left: vars.left
        }
    });
    this.div.appendTo( $("body") );
    // more stuff happens..
```

As you can see, the `Window` has a `div` property, which is a jQuery object. In it's instantiation, I declare the CSS classes **box** and **text**. **text** is not important, it's just font stuff. Here's the CSS for **box**, however.

```
.box {
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
 background: #222222;
 min-width: 10%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
}
.nav-extension {
 z-index: 3;
 padding: 8px;
 background: #000000;
 position: absolute;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

**box** is absolute at z-index 1, and another div with **nav-extension** is somewhere else on the page, also absolute and at z-index 3. However, when I add the `Window` object to my page, it appears *above* anything with **nav-extension**. All other CSS attribues, like background, still work.

I've tried altering the z-index where I instantiate the `div` in the "css" section I'm already using, but that didn't work either. What gives?

### Edit

Also, I've inspected both the div with **box** and the one with **nav-extension** with Firefox, and the "Style" tab indicates they still have their intended z-index (not overridden).

**#2**: Changed `vars.class` to `vars.styles`.

Comment: [Show us, please](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: You should not be using an identifier or property named `class` as that is a reserved word in javascript.  A CSS class name uses the property named `obj.className`.

Comment: Window? That is a bad function name.

Comment: @epascarello I disagree. `var dialogBox = new Window({...});` looks fine to me.

Comment: Changed the `vars.class` part. I could make a jsfiddle, but there's heavy PHP and multiple libraries at work here.. I might be able to strip it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you give us some DOM, please? It appears that that your box and the nav-extension-div are in different contexts. A non-static position sets up a new context, relatively to which all `z-index`es inside are processed. A simple fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/3KTyz/

```
<body>
    <style>
        .box { z-index:1; }
        .nav-extension { z-index:3; }
    </style>
    ...
        <div id="context" style="position:relative"><!-- or absolute or fixed -->
             ...
                 <div class="nav-extension"><!--
                 will be positioned +3 relatively to other elements in #context
                 -->...</div>
        </div>
    <div class="box"><!--
    will be above #context, which has (implicit) z-index:0
    -->...</div>
</body>
```

To make nav-extension appear above the box, you will either

- set #context (or one of its parents) to a z-index higher than the one of box or
- move the nav-extension-div outside any context

Comment: You were right, I had a `div` wrapping the entire page, but when the code added a `Window`, it appended it to the `body`, not within the wrapper!

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a reserved word in JavaScript and cannot be used as a property or a variable name, maybe this is the culprit.

Comment: Modern browsers allow reserved words as object properties. He should still change it for older browsers, but this won't cause anything wrong in new browsers.